# RCSI for a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2

Can I set Read Committed Snapshot Isolation for a specific query?
In order to run query like Read uncommitted, we can use "with (nolock)". Is there something similar to RCSI?
I use SQL Server 2008R2
Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms173763.aspx may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: no. The read committed snapshot database setting changes the semantics of the read committed isolation level so that it employs optimistic locking (instead of the default pessimistic). You can, however, try `set transaction isolation level snapshot` before your query and see if that will accomplish what you're looking for. NB: in order to use snapshot isolation, the database needs to be configured to allow it. Check the snapshot_isolation_state_desc column in sys.databases. If it's off, `alter database [yourdb] set ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION on` will do the trick.